# Issue implementing Energy threshold algorithm for Voice Activity Detection

Tags: speech-recognition

I am trying to implement the energy threshold algorithm for voice activity detection and not getting meaningful values for energy for frames of size wL.

```
wL = 1784 // about 40 ms (
const double decay_constant = 0.90 // some optimal value between 0 and 1
double prevrms = 1.0  // avoid DivideByZero
double threshold = some optimal value after some experimentation

for (int i = 0; i < noSamples ; i += wL)
{
   for (int j = 0; j < wL; j++)
   {
     // Exponential decay
     total = total * decay_constant;
     total += (audioSample[j] * audioSample[j]); // sum of squares
   }

   double mean = total / wL;
   double rms = Math.Round(Math.Sqrt(mean),2); // root mean sqare
   double prevrms = 1.0;

   if(rms/prevrms > threshold)
   {
  // voice detected
   }

   prevrms = rms;
   rms = 0.0;
}
```

What is wrong with the above implementation? `rms` is computed for every frame as 0.19.

The other issue is speed, as it took about 30 minutes to execute the above. Currently the implementation is O(n<sup>2</sup>). I'm working with offline data so it's not as big a deal -- accuracy is the main objective -- but any suggestions to improve efficiency would be highly appreciated.

Also, should I use other factors like auto-correlation and zero-crossing rate, or is energy alone sufficient?

Following is the summary of the WAV file (only considering clean conversational speech) I am using:

```
// WAV file information
Sampling Frequency: 44100     Bits Per Sample:  16 
Channels: 2    nBlockAlign: 4   wavdata size: 557941248 bytes
Duration: 3162.932 sec    Samples: 139485312    Time between samples: 0.0227 ms
Byte position at start of samples: 44 bytes  (0x2C)

Chosen first sample to display:  1   (0.000 ms)
Chosen end  sample to display:  1784   (40.431 ms)

16 bit max possible value is:  32767  (0x7FFF)
16 bit min possible value is: -32768  (0x8000)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found the problem. My second for loop was not setup correctly. Basically, the second for loop should be something like this:

```
for(j = i; j <= i + wL ;j++)
```

Instead of:

```
for(j = 0; j < wL; j++)
```

Which was going over the same sample values over and over again.